# Implement ABAC in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, abac

I am working on a new snowflake project where I will have to implement ABAC (Attribute Based Access Control). Although all the Rules are yet to be finalized, I am wondering if we have any documents where we can get the process flow of how to implement ABAC in snowflake.

There is no substantial documents or video of how to do it. Any body who have the experience  of implementing ABAC in snowflake, please give some insight or if can show me the direction.
It will be be really helpful .

Some more information on ABAC,
ABAC can be used to control the access of Snowflake on more granular level. Below are the examples.

1. In case if some of the table count is below 100. Then except Admin all other Roles should see mask value of certain field such as Name. If the count is more than 100 then no masking required.
2. If the user is accessing the data from country other than Canada, then He should not see the data whose country field is not in USA, Canada or Sweden. However If he is accessing the same table from within Canada He should see all the countries Records.
3. constructing the privilege on access Time. If the user is accessing the data from 9 PM to 5 PM, Then all value to be available otherwise some value to be masked.

Basically It is dynamic Access controls.

Comment: Hi - by ABAC do you mean the functionality implemented by Snowflake’s row access control policies? If not, can you update your question with an example of the sort of control you are trying to implement?

Comment: @NickW ABAC are used when we want to grant privilege on attributes level and the scenario level. I have updated my question with some sample condition. Thank you

Comment: You can probably implement these using row access policies: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-row-intro

Comment: Some of the scenarios you are requesting seem to be either row access policies or dynamic data masking.